# using construct_undefined in ruamel from_yaml

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm creating a custom yaml tag MyTag. It can contain any given valid yaml - map, scalar, anchor, sequence etc.

How do I implement class MyTag to model this tag so that ruamel parses the contents of a `!mytag` in exactly the same way as it would parse any given yaml? The `MyTag` instance just stores whatever the parsed result of the yaml contents is.

The following code works, and the asserts should should demonstrate exactly what it *should* do and they all pass.

But I'm not sure if it's working for the right reasons. . . Specifically in the `from_yaml` class method, is using `commented_obj = constructor.construct_undefined(node)` a recommended way of achieving this, and is consuming 1 and only 1 from the yielded generator correct? It's not just working by accident?

Should I instead be using something like `construct_object`, or `construct_map` or. . .? The examples I've been able to find tend to know what type it is constructing, so would either use `construct_map` or `construct_sequence` to pick which type of object to construct. In this case I effectively want to piggy-back of the usual/standard ruamel parsing for whatever unknown type there might be in there, and just store it in its own type.

```py
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap, CommentedSeq, TaggedScalar


class MyTag():
    yaml_tag = '!mytag'

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        commented_obj = constructor.construct_undefined(node)
        flag = False
        for data in commented_obj:
            if flag:
                raise AssertionError('should only be 1 thing in generator??')
            flag = True

        return cls(data)


with open('mytag-sample.yaml') as yaml_file:
    yaml_parser = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml_parser.register_class(MyTag)
    yaml = yaml_parser.load(yaml_file)

custom_tag_with_list = yaml['root'][0]['arb']['k2']
assert type(custom_tag_with_list) is MyTag
assert type(custom_tag_with_list.value) is CommentedSeq
print(custom_tag_with_list.value)

standard_list = yaml['root'][0]['arb']['k3']
assert type(standard_list) is CommentedSeq
assert standard_list == custom_tag_with_list.value

custom_tag_with_map = yaml['root'][1]['arb']
assert type(custom_tag_with_map) is MyTag
assert type(custom_tag_with_map.value) is CommentedMap
print(custom_tag_with_map.value)

standard_map = yaml['root'][1]['arb_no_tag']
assert type(standard_map) is CommentedMap
assert standard_map == custom_tag_with_map.value

custom_tag_scalar = yaml['root'][2]
assert type(custom_tag_scalar) is MyTag
assert type(custom_tag_scalar.value) is TaggedScalar

standard_tag_scalar = yaml['root'][3]
assert type(standard_tag_scalar) is str
assert standard_tag_scalar == str(custom_tag_scalar.value)
```

And some sample yaml:

```yaml
root:
  - item: blah
    arb:
      k1: v1
      k2: !mytag
        - one
        - two
        - three-k1: three-v1
          three-k2: three-v2
          three-k3: 123 # arb comment
          three-k4: 
            - a
            - b
            - True
      k3:
        - one
        - two
        - three-k1: three-v1
          three-k2: three-v2
          three-k3: 123 # arb comment
          three-k4: 
            - a
            - b
            - True
  - item: argh
    arb: !mytag
            k1: v1
            k2: 123
            # blah line 1
            # blah line 2
            k3:
              k31: v31
              k32: 
                - False
                - string here
                - 321
    arb_no_tag:
      k1: v1
      k2: 123
      # blah line 1
      # blah line 2
      k3:
        k31: v31
        k32: 
          - False
          - string here
          - 321
  - !mytag plain scalar
  - plain scalar
  - item: no comment
    arb:
      - one1
      - two2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YAML you can have anchors and aliases, and it is perfectly fine to have an object be a child of itself (using an alias). If you want to dump the Python data structure `data`:

```
data = [1, 2, 4, dict(a=42)]
data[3]['b'] = data
```

it dumps to:

```
&id001
- 1
- 2
- 4
- a: 42
  b: *id001
```

and for that anchors and aliases are necessary.

When loading such a construct, ruamel.yaml recurses into the nested data structures, but if the toplevel node has not caused a real object to be constructed to which the anchor can be made a reference, the recursive leaf cannot resolve the alias.

To solve that, a generator is used, except for scalar values. It first creates an empty object, then recurses and updates it values. In code calling the constructor a check is made to see if a generator is returned, and in that case `next()` is done on the data, and potential self-recursion "resolved".

Because you call `construct_undefined()`, you always get a generator. Practically that method could return a value if it detects a scalar node (which of course cannot recurse), but it doesn't. If it would, your code could then not load the following YAML document:

```
!mytag 1
```

without modifications that test if you get a generator or not, as is done in the code in ruamel.yaml calling the various constructors so it can handle both `construct_undefined` and e.g. `construct_yaml_int` (which is not a generator).

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer and doing so in such detail, Anthon! Much, much appreciated, and thank you for all your work on ruamel.

Just so I'm clear: if I understand everything you explained correctly, it means that `construct_undefined` as I'm using it above should work as it is?

I tried breaking it with recursive/nested tag references too & it _seems_ fine.

As you mention, elsewhere in ruamel you use something like this:

```python
if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):
    generator = data
    data = next(generator)
```

but in this case it happens to be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes it works. The key is that `contruct_undefined` always return a generator, even for scalars, so for this case testing on the type is not necessary